# How to create a shared folder using command line on a server

Tags: 10.10, server, samba, nfs, share

After following the tutorial [here](http://www.techienote.com/2010/10/file-sharing-in-ubuntu-with-nfs.html) I ran into a problem. Here is what I did.

On my server I installed `nfs-kernel-server` and edited the `/etc/exports` file to include the folder I want to share:

```
 /var *(rw,sync)
```

On my client machine I edited my `fstab` file to include share:

```
 //128.251.xxx.xxx/var/ ~/uslonsweb003 nfs #username=[username],password=[password], 0 0
```

Entered command:

```
  sudo mount -a
```

which gives this error:

```
  mount.nfs: remote share not in 'host:dir' format
```

Where did I go wrong with this setup?

Also if there is a better way (using command line) to setup a folder share on an Ubuntu 10.10 server that will be accessed by other linux and windows machines please let me know.

**UPDATE:**
The mapped drive is now not letting me create,edit,delete files or folders (readonly access)
my configuration is as follows:

client fstab file:

```
 128.251.xxx.xxx:/var /home/coreyf/uslonsweb003 nfs rw,hard,intr, 0 0
```

server exports file:

```
 /var *(rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Using Allans solution my drive mounted correctly however after putting `rw,intr` as my additional parameters I cannot create, edit and delete folders/files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can give the `~/uslonsweb003` as a directory it would have to be full eg `/home/sadmicrowave/uslonsweb003` in fstab (because there may be more than one user)

this is your original

```
//128.251.xxx.xxx/var/ ~/uslonsweb003 nfs #username=[username],password=[password], 0 0
```

you don't need the `//` at the beginning or `#username=[username],password=[password],`

and after the nfs you should have your options giving you line like this

```
128.251.xxx.xxx:/var  /home/sadmicrowave/uslonsweb003  nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
```

as the folder being shared is a **root only folder** (it acts exactly like it would on your own machine) you will need to open nautilus as root to be able to edit files.

You can find a list of nfs options and a description of what they do [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports).

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, changed it, but still getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

**On server side**
your /etc/exports file should be like this

```
/var         *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

then run

```
exportfs -av
```

**On Client side, put this entry in /etc/fstab**

```
128.251.xxx.xxx:/var  /home/sadmicrowave/uslonsweb003  nfs default 0 0
```

then run

```
mount -a
```

Vidyadhar
http://www.techienote.com